# How to format money value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Where is the problem with my sql command?

```
select REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, CAST(price AS money), 1),'.','.') as price
```

output :

```
price
-----
145,000,00
```

I want output like this

```
price
-----
145.000,00
```

Comment: Generally, you want to retrieve the data as a (decimal) number, and then set its format for display. These are usually done in different parts of your application. For example, with  `price` being a string, you cannot sum it or calculate the average for several rows.

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name  im using sql server 2016
@Kobi can u please help with my sql command?

Comment: That's an odd output format: please define it precisely (to avoid ambiguity).

Comment: @Richard: there is nothing odd about that. Some countries use the `,` for the decimal separator and the `.` as the grouping character.

Comment: The `format()` should be able to do that: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am aware of that possibility, and also that thousands separator usage varies (eg. in most cases only to the left of the decimal separator). A simple "format for <locale>" would avoid guessing about edge cases.

Comment: hi a_horse_with_no_name thanks im trying to use this select FORMAT(biaya, 'C', 'id-us') as "Price" output $ 145.000,00 but how to remove '$'

Answer (score 5):

Formatting results is usually best left for the front end.

Having said that, with SQL Server 2016, use the format function with an appropriate locale:

```
declare @m money = 145000
select format (@m, '#,###.00', 'DE-de')
```

Comment: thats what im talking about its works.. thanks dean

Comment: If you want zero to format to `0.00` instead of `.00`, use `'#,##0.00'`